# trying to update 16.04 to 18.04 ubuntu: Authentication error

Tags: networking, upgrade, authentication

I am trying to update a computer with Ubuntu 16.04 installed, but I get an authentication error, when trying to upgrade with the `do-release-upgrade` command.

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade 
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [819 B]                                           
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,248 kB]                                                  
Fetched 1,248 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                 
authenticate 'bionic.tar.gz' against 'bionic.tar.gz.gpg' 
gpg exited 2
Debug information: 


gpg: Signature made Tue 05 Jan 2021 07:18:49 PM EST using RSA key ID C0B21F32
gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found

Authentication failed
Authenticating the upgrade failed. There may be a problem with the network or with the server.
```

Im not sure what the network problem might be, I can connect to the internet just fine.

Comment: Could you please try sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade first? It seems you're missing the public gpg key for the ubuntu repositories. Maybe this will fix your issue since I don't know how to install them from the top of my head.

Comment: I just tried to run `sudo apt full-upgrade` it terminated with something like: too many errors. im trying it now with the -f option.